# doesnot match reactjs navigation routing

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm new to reactjs.I am trying to load my sidebar component and dashboard component at app starts.but when i click sidebar buttons it only loads that component and hide my sidebar 
below is the pic of that....
[below is the pic of when app starting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCKcz.png)

[below is the picture when i click sidebar button it only load the relavant component and sidebar was hidden..!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R193u.png)

this is my app.js

```
import React, {Component}from 'react';
 import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter,Switch,Route} from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from "./components/layout/Navbar";
import Signin from "./components/auth/SignIn/Signin";
import './App.css';
import New3 from "./components/new3/New3";
import Dashboard from "./components/dashboard/Dashboard";
import {StyleRoot} from "radium";
import Item from "./components/item/Item";
import Profile from "./components/profile/Profile";

function App() {
 return (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <StyleRoot>
      <div className="App">

        <Route path='/' exact component={Navbar} />
        <Route path='/' exact component={Dashboard} />
        <Route path='/signin' component={Signin} />

        <Switch>
          <Route path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
          <Route path='/item' component={Item} />
          <Route path='/profile' component={Profile} />
        </Switch>

      </div>
    </StyleRoot>
     </BrowserRouter>
 );
}

export default App;
```

how i fix this

Comment: You need to keep your sidebar component which i guess here is navbar as a parent component and keep other components as parent and remove it from routes. And then render the other routes as it's children.

Comment: I think you have to do nested routing for these situation. You can refer https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-nested-routes/